# Excel get average of a result of index+match function, see details

Tags: excel

So I have:

```
A   B   C   down here i want to get an average
            like this:
v   1   a   (*1) filter col "C" for what i have in row for col C, in this case "a", then filter col A for what I have in my row for col A, then all those rows must be counted, then sum them and then: sum/count
v   2   a
y   3   a
y   7   a
y   3   a
v   2   b
y   4   b
v   2   b
y   7   b
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `COUNTIFS` and `SUMIFS` (check Excel help for the params)

Assuming your first row starts on A1:

```
=SUMIFS($B$1:$B$9,$C$1:$C$9,C1,$A$1:$A$9,A1) / COUNTIFS($C$1:$C$9,C1,$A$1:$A$9,A1)
```

Comment: those are custom functions, right? I just found my way out with custom by using sum+count+{}, I will put then like an answer

Comment: Nope - they are built into Excel (see the help file). You didn't say which version of Excel - the function was SUMIF in 2003 but SUMIFS in 2007 and later.